# Neural network classification and regression at once

Tags: machine-learning, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I generate randomly distributed data points in space that form a ring. I do this until I get a certain number of rings, which I then convert into images. That looks like this:

Afterwards I give these images as input to a CNN to train the network for the number of rings in one image.

```
print(X_train_CNN.shape, X_test_CNN.shape, Y_train_CNN.shape, Y_test_CNN.shape)
(4000, 32, 32, 1) (1000, 32, 32, 1) (4000,) (1000,)

import tensorflow as tf
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, Dropout, Flatten, MaxPooling2D

model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(28, kernel_size=(3,3), input_shape=(imgsize, imgsize, 1)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(maxcircles,activation=tf.nn.softmax))
```

The learning curve and prediction looks like this:

As you can see the classification works well.

Besides the number of rings per image, I would also like to predict the radii of the circles.
But these are fundamentally different tasks, since one is a regression and the other classification.

is there a way to do these two tasks with only one CNN?
and how can I highlight the correctly classified circles in the image? (like in object detection)

Comment: Train multiple loss model using [The Functional API](https://keras.io/guides/functional_api/).

Answer (score 1):

As you correctly said these are 2 different tasks. For the number of circles you use a softmax function which correlates your outputs to one another. (sum = 1)
Clearly you cannot apply this output layer to a regression problem because the radii of the different circles are independent of each other. You have atleast to define a new output layer / loss function for this problem, but you could keep the base model without the output layer for both (this does of course **not** guarantee that the model will perform well for both applications)

Edit: regarding highlighting, your model only *counts* the number of circles, it does not recognize the objects, nor does it tell you which circle has been truly counted as one.

Comment: so you mean like just adding another layer to this model but this time with regression optimization function?

Comment: and how to implement to recognize the circles instead of just counting?

Comment: @jeffs yes *replacing* the output layer by a regression function. (this still means 2 different models). you'll have to see if this regression model is performing as you expect, otherwise you have to size your model differently because it is not the same task !

Comment: but how can I define the last layer if the number of rings per image varies?
For example, for one image I have to predict 4 and the other 6 radii

Comment: you have to define a Max number of rings and define a value for the radius if the number of circles is smaller than the Max. (could be 0). I suggest that you rank your outputs in descending radius length order.

Comment: if you want to recognize each circle. you have to turn to more complex image recognition techniques (i am not an expert in that field)